# on button click display hidden div and change image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div class="mac_1 tab_1 ipad_1" style=" float:right; margin:10px 20px 0 0;border:1px solid red;  display: none;"></div>
    <img src="images/mackbook.png" id="image"/>
    <a href="#" id="mac" class="button facebook" style="width:120px;  padding: 10px 0px; float:left; font: bold 22px 'Open Sans', sans-serif Helvetica, Clean, sans-serif;" OnClick="action();">Mackbook</a>    
    <a href="#" class="button facebook" style="width:80px;  padding: 10px 0px; float:left; font: bold 22px 'Open Sans', sans-serif Helvetica, Clean, sans-serif;" OnClick="action1();">Tablet</a>   
    <a href="#" class="button facebook" style="width:80px;  padding: 10px 0px; float:left; font: bold 22px 'Open Sans', sans-serif Helvetica, Clean, sans-serif;" OnClick="action2();">iPad</a> 
</div>
```

How to show the div .mac_1 and change the source of the image on button click.

Comment: I didnt get your question. Can you explain your problem with a jsFiddle ?

Comment: Where is the question, dear friend?

Comment: you have inserted your buttons in the `div` itself.. so the buttons will also not visible, and how the user will click on them to show the `div`????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with this jQuery snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $(".mac_1").css("display","block"); 
        $("#image").src("yourSource"); 
    });
});
```

Assuming you want to change the src of the image #image, and show your wrapper div .mac_1.

**UPDATE**

Would be better to place the inline styles to class "show" in css file.
Then you could go:

```
...
$(".mac_1").addClass("show");
...
```

Would be the better approach.

Comment: if i have multiple class name , like mac_1 tab_1 ipad_1 in one div

Comment: Is it possible to remove the inline styles?

If so you could pack it on one of those classes you have.
Then with jQuery or vanilla Javascript you could add another class which then triggers `display: block`

Comment: @MarcoKunz Thanks. I have improved my answer